# While attempting to set up a raspberry pi minecraft server, im getting an error message that states my Java Runtime version is too high

Tags: java, ssh, raspberry-pi3, java.lang.class

It reads: "Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.minecraft.bundler.Main
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/bundler/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0"

I ran "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar" and it was supposed to ask me about agreeing to a EULA but it gave me the stated error.

**
Extra: I am connected via SSH from the windows terminal, what command would i run to install an older version and make it the primary java runtime version. I am clueless with this as i am following a Tom's Hardware tutorial.

Comment: Your Pi has an older version of java than compiled the software.  Compile the software with an older version (if you can), or update the Pi to a newer version.  Loosely speaking, the version of java that you run on has to be not older than the version you built on.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol the software i was compiling was the official minecraft server hosting program. also, what would i enter to update the jdk?

Comment: The raspberrypi forum on stackexchange is more likely to give you accurate advice... you should ask there.